# Bootstrap 4 / Flexbox IE11 error

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have a layout of 2 columns. They must have equal heights when rendered side by side (large screen). On mobile they should stack up. I use the old BS grid for this.

The content consists of `<ul>` among others. In IE11 the lists doesn't stay inside the columns. Instead Col 2s list is rendered on top of Col 1s list.

1. How can I make each list render and stay inside it's respective column?
2. How can I skip BS grid and just use flexbox for making columns responsive?

Here's a codepen:

https://codepen.io/olefrankjensen/pen/RxXEBN?editors=1000

Comment: The BS grid in v4 uses flexbox by default.

Comment: yes but with flexbox it should be possible to avoid `col-xx` classes. Instead just use flexbox for a responsive layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

> Note: get rid of extra classes eg: `card-block justify-content-center
>   align-items-center` in section tag.

```
<div class="row justify-content-sm-center">
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <section class="ContractTemplateDetails mt-sm-0 unselectable mr-sm-2 card h-100" data-template-id="18">

       <!-- Card content -->   

   </section>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <section class="ContractTemplateDetails mt-sm-0 unselectable mr-sm-2 checked card h-100" data-template-id="18">

      <!-- Card content -->   

   </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check Demo [HERE](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/aqoVpm?editors=1000)

**Updated**

```
 <section class="ContractTemplateDetails mt-sm-0 unselectable mr-sm-2 card h-100" data-template-id="18">
        <div class="card-text-content mb-auto">
          <div class="contract-image"><img class="" src="http://freevector.co/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/29358-toy-car-outline.png" alt="Contract Basic"></div>
          <h4 class="contract-title">Contract Basic</h4>
          <ul class="contract-list">
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Impedit non </li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Impedit non.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Impedit non </li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Impedit non omfattet af serviceaftalen.</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="contract-price mt-auto">
          <h2 class="component-margin-top-small">205,00 kr./md.</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="SamCheckbox custom-control custom-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="sam-check-undefined" value="18"><i class="custom-control-indicator"></i></div>
 </section>
```

Comment: It kind of works. But I want the image and text to be in the top of the column and price to be in the bottom. Right now it seems all content in columns are distributed vertically. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Yes, you can wrap the text-content in div and give it the class `mb-auto`. I believe it will fix the issue. Please check the updated demo [here](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/aqoVpm?editors=1000)

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what was wrong with my code? You removed some classes and added others. I would like to know why my code wasnt working...!

Comment: First of all you have to understand how Flex works. Children elements immediate to parent with flex property are it's flex items. By giving properties like justify-content-center, align-items-center,etc will affect all its flex items. So I just grouped the text-content in one div and gives it class mb-auto which will push the content after it by covering the empty space between them... Hope I make you understand a bit of it. For more detail read about flexbox. If you find this answer useful upvote it. Thank you.